# Pop up on windowed plugin

Tags: javascript, windows, plugins, firebreath

I had created windowed plugin (for window OS) using one of the best cross browser friendly plugin library "Firebreath".Now I want to display the HTML popup on the window but popup goes behind the plugin window. I am aware that plugin window is always above all the HTML element so the above situation is obvious, Is there any solution to adjust the Z-order of the plugin window.

1) Window less plugin is not a option for me.
2) I don't want to wrap up my popup inside the iframe.
3) I had try SetWindowPos API on window handle but no luck.
4) I had set the z-index of my html popup to the highest but still no luck.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot display any HTML above a windowed plugin.  Period.  There are no exceptions to that rule.

Your options are to switch to windowless or to hide the plugin object (by setting width and height to 1px) when you're displaying the popup.

Note: *Do not* hide the plugin using visibility: hidden or display: none, as this will cause it to lose its window on some browsers. width/height 0 can do the same thing sometimes, so I recommend 1x1

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.Unfortunately I cant switch to windowless as I require handle of window for internal processing. 
Hiding the whole plugin also not feasible because the pop up I want to show is sort of context menu. Is there any other way ? The last option left for me is to cover my pop up with iframe(which i want to avoid)

Comment: You can still get the window handle that the browser is using with a windowless plugin, if that's good enough.  No, there is another way, and iframes won't always (ever?) work either.

Comment: iframe some times are very problematic thats why I want to avoid it. I had read a lot about windowless plugin and mostly in all post it has been said that windowless plugins are lower performant  also we have to request browser for initiating the paint request, but fortunately firebreath provided a way to to request browser for invalidating its window, but I need to test how fast browser will respond to this request as my application do the realtime drawing on window. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I'm using a webcam stream with a windowless plugin and I've never had trouble with performance.  It will not perform as well as windowed, but it might perform well enough